# Spotlight effect with css, html, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, spotlight

I've designed a spotlight effect with css, html and java. This is the link to the page: https://civitonia.com/
The spotlight follows the cursor, but as you can see, when you refresh the page or when you open it, the spotlight is not center on the page but you can see it a the bottom right. I'd like to set a "center point" or something similar that send the spotlight effect at the center of the page every time I refresh it/open it. Is it possible?

CSS:

```
.spotlight {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-image: radial gradient(circle, transparent 160px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
    200px);
    }
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        const spotlight = document.querySelector('.spotlight');
        let spotlightSize = 'transparent 160px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85) 200px)';
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => updateSpotlight(e));
        function updateSpotlight(e) {
            spotlight.style.backgroundImage = `radial-gradient(circle at ${e.pageX / window.innerWidth * 100}% ${e.pageY / window.innerHeight * 100}%, ${spotlightSize}`;
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set spotlight to center by setting its radial gradient at half of window's `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` on `"DOMContentLoaded"`.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        const spotlight = document.querySelector('.spotlight');
        let spotlightSize = 'transparent 160px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85) 200px)';
        spotlight.style.backgroundImage = `radial-gradient(circle at ${window.innerWidth/2}px ${window.innerHeight/2}px, ${spotlightSize}`;
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => updateSpotlight(e));
        function updateSpotlight(e) {
            spotlight.style.backgroundImage = `radial-gradient(circle at ${e.pageX / window.innerWidth * 100}% ${e.pageY / window.innerHeight * 100}%, ${spotlightSize}`;
        }
    });
```

Snippet:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const spotlight = document.querySelector('.spotlight');
  let spotlightSize = 'transparent 160px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85) 200px)';
  spotlight.style.backgroundImage = `radial-gradient(circle at ${window.innerWidth/2}px ${window.innerHeight/2}px, ${spotlightSize}`;
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => updateSpotlight(e));

  function updateSpotlight(e) {
    spotlight.style.backgroundImage = `radial-gradient(circle at ${e.pageX / window.innerWidth * 100}% ${e.pageY / window.innerHeight * 100}%, ${spotlightSize}`;
  }
});
```

```css
.spotlight {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 160px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="spotlight"></div>
```

---

To absolutely position the spotlight on mobile screen can use `matchMedia` method, to check the min width of the screen. Based on that, you can attach the mouse move event listener to it. In the code below, if min width is less than 800px, the spotlight is placed at center of screen else it will add the `mousemove` event listener to it.

Also, you might want to handle window resize i.e remove the `mousemove` event listener and reposition the spotlight if min width becomes < 800px and reattach the listener if becomes > 800px again (after becoming < 800px)

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
  const spotlight = document.querySelector('.spotlight');
  let spotlightSize = 'transparent 160px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85) 200px)';
  //attach mousemove event listener if media query matches. 
  if (matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 800px)').matches) {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', updateSpotlight);

    function updateSpotlight(e) {
      spotlight.style.backgroundImage = `radial-gradient(circle at ${e.pageX / window.innerWidth * 100}% ${e.pageY / window.innerHeight * 100}%, ${spotlightSize}`;
    }
    
  } else {
    spotlight.style.backgroundImage = `radial-gradient(circle at ${window.innerWidth/2}px ${window.innerHeight/2}px, ${spotlightSize}`;
  }
});
```

```css
.spotlight {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, transparent 160px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85) 200px);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .spotlight {
    position: fixed;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, transparent 160px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 200px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spotlight"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Is there a way to make it fixed (position) and not movable just in the mobile version? And to keep it following the cursor in the web version

Comment: You can use media query in css to absolutely position the spotlight on Mobile screen. Then use JavaScript's [`matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to conditionally add the above event listener to `window`.

Comment: could you upload the code above if it's possible for you? I'll understand better what you saying! Sorry I'm just learning

Comment: Should  I add @media screen and (max-width:700px) {
 
    .spotlight {
  position: absolute;
}

and then add matchMedia(.spotlight) to the script section?

Comment: yeah, but it would be `min-width`. Also, it should be `matchMedia('(min-width:800px)')`. I am including a snippet in the answer. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile) answer, for breakpoints for media queries.

Comment: <script>
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
     matchMedia('(min-width:800px)') etc etc
If I add it here it doens't work :(

Comment: If @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .spotlight {
    position:absolute; then the spotlight disappear from both versions. If I use position fixed there too it disappear just in the mobile version!

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that it isn't working as you are saying! With the second snippet the spotlight goes away in the mobile version
have a look if you want www.civitonia.com

Comment: Please Check updated Answer.

Comment: It's not working! I've updated the snippet to the website so you can check what happen in the mobile version!

Comment: In that case, I would suggest you to open another question on this website regarding the issue.